# load SVG in javascript from local file

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg

I have a javascript in html; it is showing for PNGs, JPEGs and websites(like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFnIJ.png, https://svgshare.com/i/Gzk.svg) BUT it is not showing for SVG(locally).

this is my javascript:

```js
var img = 0;
var images = [ 'abc.svg', 'syz.svg' ];
var showHide = document.getElementById('showhide');
var showHideImg = document.getElementById('showhideimg');

showHide.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  setImage();

});

function setImage() {
  if (img > images.length - 1) {
    img = 0;
  }
  var ans = document.getElementsByClassName("ans");
  for(var i = 0; i < ans.length; i++){
     ans[i].style.display = (img==0 ? "list-item": "none");
  }
  showHideImg.src = images[img++];
}
setImage();
```

and html

```html
<div class="btn">
    <div class="showhide" id="showhide">
        <img id="showhideimg">
    </div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li>abc?</li>
    <li class="ans">xyz</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 'abc.svg' file is located on same directory level as in html file?

Comment: @SivaKondapiVenkata Doesn't matter, browsers don't load multiple files locally.

Comment: If you're developing a web site, use a web server to host your content. As you have found there are lots of security restrictions you'll encounter if you don't

Answer (score 0):

Loading svg or any other type (e.g. markdown) will work when you serve working directory via HTTP.

Let me assume that your project skeleton is like this:

```
foo/
  ╠═ index.html
  ╠═ foo.js
  ╚═ abc.svg
```

Run a local http server in your project directory. If you have Python installed:

```
$ python3 -m http.server
```

After local server started, goto http://localhost:8000